# Value of objects inside objects that give undefined result

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JavaScript and I need to retrieve information stored in this way in a globally defined object.

```
var customMap ={
     totalValues:{
         total:10000
     }
     carPrices:{
         'CAR1':{date1:price1}
         'CAR2':{date2:price2}
     }
}
```

It has been fed using a function and when I launch `console.log(customMap)` I can see the whole structure of it perfectly. The problem is when I try to retrieve specific information.

I always get undefined.

I have tried with:

```
for (var i in customMap.totalValues){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(customMap.totalValues[i]);

}//It doesn't write anything in the log.

console.log(customMap.totalValues["total"]);//undefined
console.log(customMap.totalValues.total);//undefined
```

what I have achieve is when I query it in this way:

```
console.log(customMap.totalValues);

//{}
    //total: 10000

console.log(Object.values(customMap.totalValues));
console.log(Object.keys(customMap.totalValues));
console.log(Object.entries(customMap.totalValues));
```

All give same returning message:

```
//[]
    //length: 0
```

Same happens with `carPrices` objects. I cannot retrieve information for each car. I mean CAR1, CAR2...

I've run out of ideas. I don't know if is because of the way of accessing to the object is not correct, or the object is not correctly defined or just because is globally declared.

I'd appreciate all ideas that you could have.

@ Kirill Matrosov I add below the code to give an idea of my intention. As you may notice the object structure is bigger than the previous one because I try to be more precise in the issue. Anyway I have discovered that JS is not sequential and callbacks don't help me at all :S

```
var customMap = 
{
    totalValues:{},
    carPrices:{}
}

function addValuesToCustomMap(date,car,value){

    if (!customMap.carPrices[car]){
        customMap.carPrices[car] = {
            dates: {},
            carTotalValue:0,
            carPercent:0
        };
    }

    if (!customMap.carPrices[car].dates[date]){
        customMap.carPrices[car].dates[date] = value;
    }
    else if (customMap.carPrices[car].dates[date]){
        var auxValue = customMap.carPrices[car].dates[date];
        customMap.carPrices[car].dates[date] = auxValue + value;
    }

    var totalValue_byCar = customMap.carPrices[car].catTotalValue;
    customMap.carPrices[car].catTotalValue = totalValue_byCar + value;

    if(!customMap.totalValues["total"]){
        customMap.totalValues["total"]=value;
    }
    else{
        var tot = customMap.totalValues["total"]; 
        customMap.totalValues["total"]=tot+value;
    } 
}

function calculatePercentagesByCar(){
    var tot = customMap.totalValues["total"];
    for (var k in Object.keys(customMap.carPrices)){
        var totalCarPrice = customMap.carPrices[k].carTotalValue;
        var percent = totalCarPrice*100/tot;

        customMap.carPrices[k].carPercent = percent;
    }
}

/*
customMap={
        totalValue:{
            total: xxxxxx
        }
        carPrices:{
                'CAR 1': {
                            dates:{
                                    {date1:value1},
                                    (...)
                                    {dateN:valueN}
                            }
                            carTotalValue: yyyyyy,
                            carPercent: zzzz
                         }
                (...)
                'CAR N': {(...)}
        }
}
*/
```

Comment: The object could be empty at the time you are logging it. Could you test `console.log(JSON.stringify(customMap, null, 3))` and see what the output is?

Comment: When you print the reference of an object to the console (`console.log(customMap)`), it is usually not evaluated at that time, but only after you actually click onto the reference in the console. By then, it is filled with data. By using `JSON.stringify`, you evaluate the object at the time of printing and a string is actually printed.

Comment: {"totalValues": {},"carPrices": {}}

Comment: If this is the case, the data is probably fetched asynchronously, or it is defined on a later point of your code. In the async case, you need to wait for a callback to use this dataset. In the latter case, you just need to execute your code below the initialization of that object.

Comment: Yes, seems like the object is empty at that point.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: From where are you getting this data? Is it hard coded in your file or are you getting it via ajax response?

Comment: The process I followed to feed it has been: Firstly create a global empty variable CustomMap ={totalValue:{},carPrices:{}}, then I have added information using a function that accesses to the global variable. And finally I use another function to retrieve the information I need to treat. but in this point it seems that the global object is empty.

Comment: @etxe2ks please add this function "function that accesses to the global variable" to post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var customMap ={
     totalValues:{
         total:10000
     },
     carPrices:{
         'CAR1':{date1:'price1'},
         'CAR2':{date2:'price2'}
     }
};

console.log(customMap.totalValues.total);

console.log(customMap.carPrices.CAR1);

console.log(customMap.carPrices.CAR2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is broken.

```
var customMap ={
 totalValues:{
     total:10000
 }, // here you are missing a comma.
 carPrices:{
     'CAR1':{date1:price1} // Is this value filled by the variable price1? If not is broken and should be 'price1'.
     'CAR2':{date2:price2} // Is this value filled by the variable price2? If not is broken and should be 'price2'.
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you J.Lindebro. Indeed it's a mistake I made when writting the issue. In my code is with coma :S and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you forgot to separate the values in the `customMap` object and the `carPrices` property with commas.

Here's a working example of what you've tried

```js
var customMap = {
     totalValues:{
         total:10000
     },
     carPrices:{
         'CAR1':{'date1':'price1'},
         'CAR2':{'date2':'price2'}
     }
}

for (var i in customMap.totalValues){
    console.log('property:', i);
    console.log('value:', customMap.totalValues[i]);

}
/*
property: total
value: 10000
*/

console.log(customMap.totalValues["total"]);//10000
console.log(customMap.totalValues.total);//10000

console.log(customMap.totalValues);

console.log(Object.values(customMap.totalValues));
console.log(Object.keys(customMap.totalValues));
console.log(Object.entries(customMap.totalValues));
```

Comment: Sorry about the mistake of commas when writting the issue here, in my code they have commas. (thank you A Rather Long Name)